# Django fail to connect to postgres database in gitlab ci

Tags: django, docker, continuous-integration

I have the following .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
image: python:3.6

stages:
  - lint
  - test

services:
  - postgres:10.1-alpine

cache:
  paths:
  - /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/

before_script:
  - python -V
  - pip install pipenv
  - pipenv install --dev

lint:
  stage: lint
  script:
  - pipenv run pylint --output-format=text --load-plugins pylint_django project/ | tee pylint.txt
  - score=$(sed -n 's/^Your code has been rated at \([-0-9.]*\)\/.*/\1/p' pylint.txt)
  - echo "Pylint score was $score"
  - pipenv run anybadge --value=$score --file=pylint.svg pylint
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - pylint.svg

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - pipenv run python manage.py test
```

And I am connecting to the database like this :

```
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'db', # set in docker-compose.yml
        'PORT': 5432 # default postgres port
    }
}
```

For now, I just have this tests in `users/tests.py` :

```
from .models import CustomUser
from django.test import TestCase

class LogInTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.credentials = {
            'username': 'testuser',
            'password': 'secret'}
        CustomUser.objects.create_user(**self.credentials)
    def testLogin(self):
        # send login data
        response = self.client.post('/users/login/', self.credentials, follow=True)
        # should be logged in now
        self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_authenticated)
```

Which fails with the following error :

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

In development, I use the following docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10.1-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=changemeinprod
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

With this Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.6

# Set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY ./Pipfile /code/Pipfile
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system --skip-lock --dev

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

I don't understand why the app cab't connect to the database in the CI but connect just fine in the development ENV with docker

Answer (score 4):

In your `docker-compose.yml` you set the service name as `db`, and django `settings.py` for use `db`, but in gitlab will use the image name as the name of the service, `postgres` in case.

You have two options:

1 - Use environments variables in `settings.py`, some example [here](https://godjango.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-python/)

2 - Set a `alias` in gitlab-ci.yml, like:

`services:
 - name: postgres:10.1-alpine
   alias: db`

link: [gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-and-services-from-gitlab-ciyml)